# Game of Thrones Main Title buzzing

Tags: theory, string-instruments

I have listened to this recording multiple times from multiple sources in addition to the actual show.

In the Game of Thrones soundtrack, Main Title at 0:08, a cello (or other low range stringed instrument) begins playing.  From what I can hear, there is a buzzing sound in addition to the note the instrument is playing.  As the rest of the orchestra plays their parts, this buzzing sound seems to be drown out. However, it is again apparent, though fainter, around 1:34.

Is this the result of a deliberate technique designed to give the music a rougher texture or is this a flaw in the instrument, bow, or performer?

Comment: You may want to check out: http://songexploder.net/ramin-djawadi

Comment: Rumor has it the theme music was generated with synths.  https://www.pri.org/stories/2014-02-19/why-violinist-wants-change-opening-theme-song-game-thrones

Comment: @CarlWitthoft- I'd wondered that myself.  Sounds synthetic to me too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm hearing a couple of things. When the Bass comes in at the beginning, there is a drum roll that comes in at the same time as the bass.  There is some string rumble at the second section.

I'm listing to a youtube of it, so it doesn't have the clarity to really tell, but you may be hearing the low string rumble that the bass gives off. Acoustically you generally don't hear the bow drag rumble, but when recording with a mic placed close you pick it up. The mixing engineer may have kept or even emphasized this sound for dramatic effect.

It is a result of the way a bow works to vibrate the strings, where the sticky rosin on the bow hair catches and then releases the string, making it vibrate.  A player can grind this for a dirty effect, but in this case it is more likely something that was brought out in the recording process.

Comment: I don't hear it on the YouTube version either. Could be the quality of the track on that channel. I did hear staggered strings, so perhaps the delay between the main string and the staggered one is causing some sort of phasing effect.